# Angular Project not run on docker with visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I created a new web project on Visual Studio 2019 using the built in Angular template (ASP.NET Core 3).

[image]

Then, i Added a docker support using the wizard of visual studio (Right click on the project name -> Add -> Docker Support).

[image]

While the project working fine when i launching it from the visual studio using IIS Express, i am getting the following error when launching it using Docker:

[image]

[image]

I assume that something is missing in the docker file. This is the content of mine:

[image]

Comment: I am totally strange to .NET but for me the error is quite clear: the application cannot find a defined port to listen on. Where do you set that?

Comment: I have the same problem. When you add a new angular project, the option to provide docker support is actually disabled. So apparently there is simply no dotnetcore docker image with nodejs installed?

Answer (score 3):

For this error, it is caused that `node` is not installed in `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim` image, try to change your dockerfile to install `node` with version 10 or later.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim AS base
# BEGIN MODIFICATION - Node is needed for development (but not production)
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes nodejs
# END MODIFICATION

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Comment: This probably works, but i would prefer a base image that comes with nodejs. Apparently MS didnt feel like providing such an image: when you create a new angular project in visual studio 2019, they have actually disabled the "docker support" checkbox.

Comment: This solution allows me to run my project in Debug configuration. But when I try to run it in Release configuration it fails like this:
1>  /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmp3125b5c365644a97b48cabba4ab34ca2.exec.cmd: npm: not found
1>/src/WebApplication7/WebApplication7.csproj(41,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127.
any ideas?

Comment: @Davy, I have the same issue as Robert Hegner.  Do you know how to get this working in release mode? Thanks.